# Laravel how to change the public_path after deployment

Tags: laravel

I was working on my project on local and I used image upload and I was storing the image in public_path and get it by asset()

after deployment the project structure changed so the public_html contains the public folder content
and it also contains 'project name' folder that includes the rest of project folders, so the public_path is different now and it creates a new public folder inside the 'project name folder' and I need it to store in the public outer folder

Comment: what else I can use to achieve my goal

Comment: Do you mean that your server has something like `username/public_html/app-name/public/`?

Answer (score 2):

The correct suggested solution to resolve this issue, is to move your existing files in Laravel `public` directory to the adequate required document root folder , example `public_html` (the most used in shared servers running WHM/CPanel)
then go to your `public_html/index.php` and add, just after the line where `$app` is created:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() { return __DIR__; });
```

this will bind the document root to he current file path, where index.php exists
also, to fix the path for scripts used in CLI mode or Artisan script, you should add the code below to the file **/bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() { return base_path().'/public_html'; });
```

this will bind Laravel document root with the correct one, in this case we are linking it to `public_html` folder, you can also put the full path to your document root instead of the dynamic approach.